# increment git version with travis when publishing a repo

Tags: git, npm, travis-ci

I want to [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) to publish npm whenever I accept dependent bot changes. I have added npm email and auth token.

My travis configuration is this right now (which I am not sure is correct or not)

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
install:
  - "npm install"
script:
  - "npm run test"
before_deploy: 

deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: "$npm_email"
  api_key: "$npm_token"
  on:
    branch: production
```

Where npm test looks like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
 }
```

How can I make travis to increment npm package version  and have that package version also on the git? same for changelog.md?

Comment: Tagging is usually the way that this is done, since normally a human has to make semantic versioning decisions.  Are you willing to do that, or do you want a completely automated solution?

Comment: @bk2204 I don't mind doing it using tagging.

Comment: @bk2204 Can you help me with how I can achieve it using tagging?

Answer (score 2):

A nice fully-fledged solution for this is **[semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release)**.

When using semantic-release, your commit messages need to adhere to [a specific format](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/#commit-message-format). You will then configure your travis pipeline to run semantic-release, which parses your commits, generates a changelog, a new version number, and pushes the changes as a new commit (for the changelog) and a new tag to your repo.

The setup is a little more involved, but you will have a stable solution which ensures your version numbers make sense. Also, you get "free" automatically generated changelogs.

There is also [a recipe for travis](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/recipes/recipes/travis) which should help to get it set up.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a dependency version is a manual runtime or programming language task, Travis is CI & CD tool , you SHOULD NOT automated with travis.

You might need a tool to inspect packages, dependencies like [Snyk](https://snyk.io/) so it might check vulnerabilities or posible upgradable packages.

Anyway under your own risk you could upgrade your packages in before_install like this:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
before_install:
  - "npm update <package name>"  ## change your package to update.
install:
  - "npm install"
script:
  - "npm run test"
before_deploy: 

deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: "$npm_email"
  api_key: "$npm_token"
  on:
    branch: production
```

Comment: I understood the question as being about it's **own** version number, not the version of dependencies.

Comment: does he? if so , I have waste my time :( ... anyway he ask for "increment my npm package" and title says "increment git version" though